# Exchange realtime data between iOS app and server

Tags: iphone, ios, tcp, ip

How to implement a two way IP/TCP connection between iPhone and host.

Comment: Do you want to physically push a key on your computer or what?

Comment: I believe that what you are looking for is using so called sockets, so you would typically have a port to communicate with the server and set up a socket. I think some googling on sockets can help you. Since I don't know which language you are writing your PC server in I can't advice but I found this tutorial to be quite helpful in getting up and running http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm hope you get some help out of it and that perhaps someone with more knowledge can fill in on the details.

Comment: But I can send data through the socket like in step#1 from client to host. I am not sure, how can I send the data back from the host to client? In other words, I want the server to act as a client and the device as the host for step #2 - Server code can be anything, C++/C#..etc.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the problem, and see that my suggestion weren't much help. I am not an expert at this at all, and I am afraid that I haven't got much to help with that specific step. All I can think about right now, is that it might be possible to poll for the answers, however that is probably not "good enough" for you. (I mean that you could expose on the server and ask on the client side with some time interval). I don't know a good solution I hope someone with more knowledge will give you an answer soon, and good luck.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I did think of polling, but I am guessing/hoping there will be some event driven solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP/IP communication is two-way communication.

True: server has to be the one to listen for the connection and client has to re-establish the connection in case it is lost.

But during the time of the connection client can send messages to server (when needed) and vice-versa.

To keep the connection alive (it can be killed after being inactive for certain period of time) you can periodically send some dummy (keepalive) strings: usually from client to server but it can go the other way around.

Since you allready know how to establish a connection between iOS client and a server (it can be PC based or whatever) and you know how to send strings from client to server - you just have to implement the server-to-client communication.

Exactly how to do that depends on which type of sockets you use in iOS and PC-server.

A nice tutorial from Cesare Rocchi can be found here: [How To Create A Socket Based iPhone App and Server](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server)

There's also a very useful and well documented socket wrapper for Cocoa called [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) from Robbie Hanson on GitHub.

**EDIT:**

In your case you would usually have at least one socket-based client on one side. Client is responsible to try to reestablish the connection in case it is lost (or to establish it for the first time).

On the other side you have a *listener* socket - a socket, that listens for new connections. For each new connection (from a client) it spawns a new socket and from there on you can handle two way communication. So client->server is neccessery only during establishing the connection.

Comment: Correct - I am not an expert when it comes to IP/TCP. But, almost all of the stuff I have seen on this subject, expects to get an answer from server within same request. I have yet to see an example that actually makes the server act as a client and the device as a host. I know there should be a way, chat program might be an example of this.

Comment: That is usually the case when it comes to servers in true meaning of word. In some cases it goes like this: clients connects and sends requests - server responds - clients accepts response and disconnects. But you can keep connection alive for as long as you wish. And server can send some data (event) on it's on initiative - no polling needed. Polling is still recommended just to check if connection is still alive. If it's not you simply reconnect.

Comment: That's great. I guess I just need to find out how I can send "events" from server back to client. In fact, this is what I need my program for, events.

Comment: It takes some tweaking and testing to to make things robust (reconnecting in case of loosing connection etc.) but it can surely be done.  Just found an article that helped me a lot a few years ago: [iPhone Network Programming](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43551). But i'd suggest using CocoaAsyncSocket - it's easy to use once you spend a day or two figuring it out :)

Comment: I got it to work, I think I should have tested my code a bit more before i posted. The problem was like you said, to make sure the connection isn't getting lost. Thanks